# Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013

I'm working on a project in work and I just have a query regarding a page. So I want to effectively place an excel file "behind" a page and then on the GUI of the page have a search criteria which will show users their search results from said excel document ?

Is this possible to do ? I can't seem to figure it out if so.

Thank you in advance for your help.

C

Answer (score 0):

Depends on edition. (Foundation, Std, Ent)

You can:

- Import the Excel file to a SharePoint list, and then use search.
- Store the Excel file in a library, connect to it using Business Connectivity Services (BCS / BDC), display it as an External list, and the use search.
- Store it in a library, and use custom JavaScript to call the Office Online Server's REST API. (You can return ranges, not sure about search methods.)
- Setup the Excel file for Excel Web Services, publish to SharePoint and add an Excel Services Web Part. (Enterprise Edition Only)

Comment: Thanks for the help Mike! I believe it is Foundation edition I'm working on. I have created a custom list and uploaded a test excel file onto the list. I have the code for a custom search box ready I just can't find where the "Edit Source" button is to add this ?